# Electronic Piggy Bank

Tags: code-golf

A [piggy bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggy_bank) is a container used to collect coins in. For this challenge use the four US coins: [quarter, dime, nickel, and penny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_of_the_United_States_dollar).

## Challenge

Your challenge is to create an electronic piggy bank. Write a program (or function) that when run (or called), outputs (or returns) the count of each coin you have, as well as the total amount the coins amount to.

## Input

A string, array, etc...(your choice) of the coins into your piggy bank(case insensitive).

```
 Q - Quarter(Value of 25)
 D - Dime(Value of 10)
 N - Nickel(Value of 5)
 P - Penny(Value of 1)
```

## Output

The count of coins from the input and the total amount, separated by the non-integer delimiter of your choice. (The order in which you output the coin totals does not matter, but the total coin value(sum) must be the last element)

## Examples

```
 Input          ->       Output

 P              ->       1,0,0,0,1 or 0,0,0,1,1 or 0,0,1,0,1 or 1,1
 N              ->       0,1,0,0,5
 D              ->       0,0,1,0,10 
 Q              ->       0,0,0,1,25
 QQQQ           ->       0,0,0,4,100
 QNDPQNDPQNDP   ->       3,3,3,3,123
 PPPPPPPPPP     ->       10,0,0,0,10
 PNNDNNQPDNPQND ->       3,6,3,2,113
```

## Rules

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes for each language wins!

Comment: Can we take input in lowercase?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes you can

Comment: Can we output a list, rather than a delimited string?

Comment: @Mnemonic Of course, a list will be separated by each element.

Comment: *The order of the coins in the total*. May we give it in the order of appearance in the input?

Comment: @Adam Yes. I rephrased it, please feel free to edit if you feel you can word it better.

Comment: So if the order may be inferred from the input, may we omit 0s? It will still be clear which letters the each number refers to.

Comment: @Adám Yes you can omit the 0's

Comment: May we choose symbols other than `QDNP`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No you must use either `QDNP` or `qdnp` as the input

Comment: Is this output format too far off? 19 byte answer that I'm not sure is valid: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/wjTEyFSzWO9RwyJTg0cNC4B08KFFtlr@tv//F@TlpeTlFRak5BUUAgA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Not at all! As long as I can determine the count of the each coin plus the total it is fine for me! Awesome answer!

Comment: I feel like there should be a [money] tag.

Comment: Can the input list be empty (no coins) and if so what should the output be. In particular, may the sum be empty instead of `0` ?

Comment: If only part of the challenge were to actually draw an ASCII piggy bank around the output.

Comment: @TonHospel the list cannot be empty, so don't worry about that scenario

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @Rod

```python
C=map(input().count,'QDNP')
print C+[sum(map(int.__mul__,C,[25,10,5,1]))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoAgEADQva9wU@mIChqbbI6cI0QqKMhT8hz6egta3vTCQ4fHNmfVOxvEiSGRkNXqExJwPYwTl0W4TySmyjkmJ/5GlTEuXcaAgrntoKnhY5FyyZlrPY3M4saidzuj28aDvw)

Comment: You can replace `a*b for a,b in zip(C,[25,10,5,1])` with `map(int.__mul__,C,[25,10,5,1])` to save few bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```r
function(n)c(x<-table(factor(n,c("P","N","Q","D"))),x%*%c(1,5,25,10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsMgEIDhvU8hlsBdMdAUsmV0PuIcMqSiJRBU9AJ5eyu0w799/Ll6MfXVn8HyHgMEtHBNPW/vw4HfLMcMQVmQs1SSWqalJSKqq3t0FgY1qteohidi9dCg@aNfiDcPhXNJx87tQqSJzKxpNqSbkLgsw7qiuAsfs3BbcSJ6wa7wHj4inTnF4kr9Ag)

Takes input as a vector of individual characters. Converts them to `factors` and `tabulate`s them, then computes the values with a dot product.

For ease of testing purposes, I've added a way to convert from test cases above to the input that the function is expecting.

This barely beats out storing the coin names as vector `names`, which means that the approach below would be likely be golfier if we had more coin types:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```r
function(n)c(x<-table(factor(n,names(v<-c(P=1,N=5,Q=25,D=10)))),x%*%v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCsMgFEDRvV/xsASexUBTyBY3Z9E5ZLCiJZCqqAn5e5uxF852c/Mw9c3vwdY1BgzU4jn11bw3h97YGjMGFszXFTym3qLiA5N8ZJq/Rib48KRX7Owe3UGbR4tEE/aH0pvHUnNJ21qRKCmFlFoJqbQU10HoPA/LQuEOPmZwpjiIHqordQ0fSHtOsbjSfg)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
a,b,c,d=map(input().count,'PNDQ')
print a,b,c,d,a+b*5+c*10+d*25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnSSdZJ8U2N7FAIzOvoLREQ1MvOb80r0RHPcDPJVBdk6ugKDOvRAGqTidRO0nLVDtZy9BAO0XLyPT/f6AyPxc/v8AAF7@AQD8XdQA)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
l=map(input().count,'PNDQ')
a,b,c,d=l
print l+[a+b*5+c*10+d*25]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8c2N7FAIzOvoLREQ1MvOb80r0RHPcDPJVBdkytRJ0knWSfFNoeroCgzr0QhRzs6UTtJy1Q7WcvQQDtFy8g09v9/oGI/Fz@/wAAXv4BAPxd1AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```apl
1 5 10 25(⊢,+.×)'PNDQ'+.=¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRDBVMFQwMFI1ONR12LdLT1Dk/XVA/wcwlU19azPbTiUVcTUJmCjnqAOheI8oNQLhAqEEoBAZTl5xIAwxCRADiA8v38XPz8AgNc/ECK1AE)

Tacit function. Takes input as a vector in the format `,'<input>'`.

Thanks to ngn for one byte!

#### How?

```apl
1 5 10 25(⊢,+.×)'PNDQ'+.=¨⊂ ⍝ Main function, tacit.
                          ⊂ ⍝ Enclose
                         ¨  ⍝ Each character of the input
                      +.=   ⍝ Sum the number of matched characters
                'PNDQ'      ⍝ From this string
1 5 10 25(  +.×)            ⍝ Multiply the values with the left argument, then sum them.
          ⊢,                ⍝ And append to the original vector of coins.
```

Comment: `1⊥∘.=∘'PNDQ'` -> `'PNDQ'+.=¨⊂`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
`p˜q`¬£èX
pUí*38#éìH)x
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YHCYcWCso+hYCnBV7SozOCPp7EgpeA==&input=InBubmRubnFwZG5wcW5kIg==) Takes input in lowercase

#### Explanation

```
`p˜q`¬         Split the compressed string "pndq" into chars, giving ["p", "n", "d", "q"].
      £        Map each char X to
       èX      the number of occurrences of X in the input.
<newline>      Set variable U to the resulting array.
 Uí*           Multiply each item in U by the corresponding item in
    38#é         38233
        ìH       converted to base-32, giving [1, 5, 10, 25].
           x   Take the sum.
p              Append this to the end of U.
               Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Trying to figure out a way to golf away the comma, not having much luck so far.

Comment: [Got it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IlBORFEirKPoWApwVe0qNeIgcEEyNSl4&input=IlBOTkROTlFQRE5QUU5EIg==)

Comment: And [save another byte](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YHCYcWCso+hYCnBV7So14iBwQTI1KXg=&input=InBubmRubnFwZG5wcW5kIg==) by taking input in lowercase.

Comment: [Knocked another byte off](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YHCYcWCso+hYCnBV7SozOCPp7EgpeA==&input=InBubmRubnFwZG5wcW5kIg==)

Comment: @Shaggy Impressive, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ċÐ€“PNDQ”µæ.“¢¦½ı‘ṭ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9qZWxsef//xIvDkOKCrOKAnFBORFHigJ3CtcOmLuKAnMKiwqbCvcSx4oCY4bmt////IlBOTkROTlFQRE5QUU5EIg)

#### How it works

```
ċÐ€“PNDQ”µæ.“¢¦½ı‘ṭ    Main link. Arguments: s (string)
 Ð€“PNDQ”              For each char in "PNDQ":
ċ                        Count the occurrences of the char in s.
                       Collect the results in an array. Call this a.
         µ             Start a new monadic chain. Argument: a
          æ.           Take the dot product of a with
            “¢¦½ı‘       [1, 5, 10, 25].
                  ṭ    Tack this onto the end of a.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
!'PNDQ'=Xst[l5X25]*s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X1E9wM8lUN02orgkOsc0wsg0Vqv4/3@goJ@Ln19ggItfQKCfizoA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F9RPcDPJVDdNqK4JDrHNMLINFar@L9BcoRLyH/1AHUudT8gdgHiQBAGAhDl5xIAw0BuAByAOH5@Ln5@gQEufiBpdQA).

#### Explanation with example

Consider input `'PNNDNNQPDNPQND'` as an example. The stack contents are shown upside down, i.e. the top element appears below.

```
!        % Implicit input: string (row vector of chars). Transpose into a
         % column vector of chars
         % STACK: ['P';
                   'N';
                   'N';
                   'D';
                   'N';
                   'N';
                   'Q';
                   'P';
                   'D';
                   'N';
                   'P';
                   'Q';
                   'N';
                   'D']
'PNDQ'   % Push this string (row vector of chars)
         % STACK: ['P';
                   'N';
                   'N';
                   'D';
                   'N';
                   'N';
                   'Q';
                   'P';
                   'D';
                   'N';
                   'P';
                   'Q';
                   'N';
                   'D'],
                  'PNDQ'
=        % Implicit input. Test for equality, element-wise with broadcast
         % STACK: [1 0 0 0;
                   0 1 0 0;
                   0 1 0 0;
                   0 0 1 0;
                   0 1 0 0;
                   0 1 0 0;
                   0 0 0 1;
                   1 0 0 0;
                   0 0 1 0;
                   0 1 0 0;
                   1 0 0 0;
                   0 0 0 1;
                   0 1 0 0;
                   0 0 1 0]
Xs       % Sum of each column
         % STACK: [3 6 3 2]
t        % Duplicate
         % STACK: [3 6 3 2],
                  [3 6 3 2]
[l5X25]  % Push array [1 5 10 25]
         % STACK: [3 6 3 2],
                  [3 6 3 2],
                  [1 5 10 25]
*        % Multiply, element-wise
         % STACK: [3 6 3 2],
                  [3 30 30 50]
s        % Sum
         % STACK: [3 6 3 2],
                  113
         % Implicitly display
```

Comment: `!'PNDQ'=Xst[l5X25]!Y*` is 21 bytes. although I admit I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks, but the challenge says "_the_ non-integer delimiter of your choice", so I assume only one delimiter is allowed

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. Ah well.

Comment: I think the 21 byte solution is OK... [OP commented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160678/electronic-piggy-bank#comment389488_160678) something to that effect

Comment: @Giuseppe Great! Down to 20 bytes then. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>33</s> 27 bytes

5 bytes saved thanks to Adam

Prompts for screen input of coin string.

```
n,+/1 5 10 25×n←+⌿⎕∘.='PNDQ'
```

Comment: Save 5 bytes: `n,+/1 5 10 25×n←+⌿⎕∘.='PNDQ'`

Comment: @ngn Thanks. Old age is getting the better of me :(

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>63</s> 61 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Shaggy*

Takes input as an array of characters. Outputs `P,N,D,Q,total`.
Inspired by [ovs' Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160699/58563).

```js
a=>eval(a.join`++,`+`++,[P,N,D,Q,P+N*5+D*10+Q*25]`,P=N=D=Q=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBBC4IwFMDxe59it6lba7Pstk47P7azCA7TUMRFRV/ftLAMnI@33X784TX2ae/Frb4@tp07l30leytP5dO2gWWNq7ucEJqT8U81BaqooZpAlBAVCU5MFCdZTrUEqaSRPOwL191dW7LWXYIqSBljWGM0nywM0W6HUiQo4tMKlG0WKHjoKCaaLFPlp18t@LI1q/bDY0/XDIPX7GHs@sKg9PTwDO/pb0W8X8b6O/j/znx@aE9ZAygAoxWMcTwvH9/ZeLBiKPcv)

---

## Original answer, 73 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters. Outputs `Q,D,N,P,total`.

```js
a=>a.map(c=>o[o[4]+='521'[i='QDNP'.search(c)]*5||1,i]++,o=[0,0,0,0,0])&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZG9DsIgFEZ3n4LJ21rEUq0bTp0JnQkDwVZrVJrWOPnulfhTO4Af32U7OYF70nfdm65pb8ur3VdDzQbNdppcdBsZtrPSyo1KGOQZBdkwKAsugPSV7swxMrFa5I8HxY1KEmyZTPHnqHg@t4Ox196eK3K2h6iOJCEEBKBpVByj1QpJlOJPqStSMw/K/6L0ded@tAijdBSnfrYMsCPomgW8pQt42M2EpWlIzAvxHZjAa/wrzdZ@WIyBwD//ebLgvOC8FG7XTg4jnL2c27eZOvPwBA)

Comment: Very nicely done! You can [knock 2 bytes off](https://tio.run/##fdBBC4IwFMDxe59it6lba7Pstk47P7azCA7TUMRFRV/ftLAMnI@33X784TX2ae/Frb4@tp07l30leytP5dO2gWWNq7ucEJqT8U81BaqooZpAlBAVCU5MFCdZTrUEqaSRPOwL191dW7LWXYIqSBljWGM0nywM0W6HUiQo4tMKlG0WKHjoKCaaLFPlp18t@LI1q/bDY0/XDIPX7GHs@sKg9PTwDO/pb0W8X8b6O/j/znx@aE9ZAygAoxWMcTwvH9/ZeLBiKPcv) by shuffling some stuff around.

Answer (score 3):

### Excel (Polish language version), 150 bytes

The input is in A1. The formulas are in cells `B1`-`F1`:

```
cell  formula
------------------------------
B1    =DŁ(A1)-DŁ(PODSTAW(A1;"Q";""))
C1    =DŁ(A1)-DŁ(PODSTAW(A1;"D";""))
D1    =DŁ(A1)-DŁ(PODSTAW(A1;"N";""))
E1    =DŁ(A1)-DŁ(PODSTAW(A1;"P";""))
F1    =B1*25+C1*10+D1*10+E1
```

resulting in output of number of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennys and the sum in cells `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, `E1` and `F1` respectively.

**English language version (162 bytes):**

```
cell  formula
------------------------------
B1    =LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"Q";""))
C1    =LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"D";""))
D1    =LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"N";""))
E1    =LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"P";""))
F1    =B1*25+C1*10+D1*10+E1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> <s>26</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
X5T25)s.•50†•S¢=*O=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/wjTEyFSzWO9RwyJTg0cNC4B08KFFtlr@tv//F@TlpeTlFRak5BUUAgA)

---

```
X                   # Push 1.
 5                  # Push 5.
  T                 # Push 10.
   25               # Push 25.
     )s             # Wrap stack to array, swap with input.
       .•50†•       # Push 'pndq'.
             S      # Push ['p','n','d','q'] (split).
              ¢     # Count (vectorized).
               =    # Print counts, without popping.
                *   # Multiply counts by [1,2,10,25]
                 O  # Sum.
                  = # Print.
```

---

## Dump:

```
Full program: X5T25)s.•50†•S¢=*O=
current >> X  ||  stack: []
current >> 5  ||  stack: [1]
current >> T  ||  stack: [1, '5']
current >> 2  ||  stack: [1, '5', 10]
current >> )  ||  stack: [1, '5', 10, '25']
current >> s  ||  stack: [[1, '5', 10, '25']]
current >> .  ||  stack: [[1, '5', 10, '25'], 'pnndnnqpdnpq']
current >> S  ||  stack: [[1, '5', 10, '25'], 'pnndnnqpdnpq', 'pndq']
current >> ¢  ||  stack: [[1, '5', 10, '25'], 'pnndnnqpdnpq', ['p', 'n', 'd', 'q']]
current >> =  ||  stack: [[1, '5', 10, '25'], [3, 5, 2, 2]]
[3, 5, 2, 2]
current >> *  ||  stack: [[1, '5', 10, '25'], [3, 5, 2, 2]]
current >> O  ||  stack: [[3, 25, 20, 50]]
current >> =  ||  stack: [98]
98
stack > [98]
```

Printed Output:

```
[3, 25, 20, 50]\n98 or [P, N, D, Q]\n<Sum>
```

Because something was printed, the ending stack is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>163</s> 136 bytes

Thanks to @raznagul for saving alot of bytes there!

```cs
n=>{var m="";int c=0,i=0,k=0;for(var v=new[]{1,5,10,25};i<4;m+=k+",",c+=k*v[i++],k=0)foreach(var x in n)k+=x=="PNDQ"[i]?1:0;return m+c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNBa4MwFMfP81M8vFRnJnasl9l0h5bt0ollhx3EQ8jSNlQjJKnrED@7i5stdbCtYOAP7yX5/94L5FF1QwvJGpoRpSCWxUaSHCrrSmmiOYWy4G/wTLhwlJZcbJIUiNwo11yxXj6UZrn/uBd02sXzIssY1bwQyn9igklO/SVXekq3RM4QfENmsAbcCDyrSiIhx7YdcqGB4gBxox0OwnUhnfawxIK9J2k1RhM0DtDtpA759C7MPbzzbGQjaoLrMuGel7Y@1/gYodsv7wG4AOHuPHzA2I6jxcpOePowvg9CyfReCsg9GtZNaFlwtlqrZkrPiWIKMJgG4KLnJWmPU/Wydl1MqkbxqEYwBBANBSyGAlYGMMyPzjScFRktjOKO@Xs@rFbcMf/W8BrRWc/HeNXxj3v9t9W9kvWPf9@NDjjHAWjH5zQI7j9/@9S4UEXG/FfJNVtywZy10zJcN@wXt6yr2qqbTw)

---

Old version:

```cs
n=>{var v=new[]{1,5,10,25};string l="PNDQ",m="";int c=0,i,j,k;for(i=0;i<4;i++){for(j=0,k=0;j<n.Length;j++)k+=n[j]==l[i]?1:0;m+=k+",";c+=k*v[i];k=0;}m+=c;return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVE9T8MwEJ3Jrzh5SoipUkQXXJehEVOJUjEwRBki46bOhyPZbhCK8tuDQ0shUImTfLbfez77@Zi@YY3iA6syrSFWTa6yGjrnSpvMCAZtI17hKRPS1UYJmScpZCrXnpU4z@/a8Hr2eJBseWQxHOcV7IAOkq66NlPQUsnfkrSb4wWeB/h20ZOjDCqK4ijcIlxThIiQBhgNsMAFLsmuUa6gARHLOyJ83@tGoLB0acFiKWcbLnOzJ4XlSp/KpEgprRKRPszvA1L7tPQRRoTZxXVrYTKe6y3OiOLmoCTUpB@I48CPOJs0XJt1prkGCvb1Z2Ki7ia7MVCMMKBoTOGYrLW/mq2Ni3gUxl/jEh@f4yIbRWEUbeMwGgugiaD/ZdN@Jc/YHk5N/XQLQn679v7xeWr9upG6qfjsRQnDN0Jyd@eONTyPTO93nKve6YcP)

Comment: I've managed to golf your soultion down to [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##pZNBa4MwFMfP81M8vFRnJnasl9l0h5bt0ollhx3EQ8jSNlQjJKnrED@7i5stdbCtYOAP7yX5/94L5FF1QwvJGpoRpSCWxUaSHCrrSmmiOYWy4G/wTLhwlJZcbJIUiNwo11yxXj6UZrn/uBd02sXzIssY1bwQyn9igklO/SVXekq3RM4QfENmsAbcCDyrSiIhx7YdcqGB4gBxox0OwnUhnfawxIK9J2k1RhM0DtDtpA759C7MPbzzbGQjaoLrMuGel7Y@1/gYodsv7wG4AOHuPHzA2I6jxcpOePowvg9CyfReCsg9GtZNaFlwtlqrZkrPiWIKMJgG4KLnJWmPU/Wydl1MqkbxqEYwBBANBSyGAlYGMMyPzjScFRktjOKO@Xs@rFbcMf/W8BrRWc/HeNXxj3v9t9W9kvWPf9@NDjjHAWjH5zQI7j9/@9S4UEXG/FfJNVtywZy10zJcN@wXt6yr2qqbTw). To many changes to list.

Comment: @raznagul Great solution! May I ask why you switched the input to a generic list instead of an array? AFAIK you can iterate over the characters of a string without using a list.

Comment: That is a remnant from an earlier version, so I could use `n.Count` instead of `n.Length`. As that was dropped entirely you can use `string` now.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

```
1 5 10 25(],1#.*)1#.'PNDQ'=/]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYoxC4MwFIR3f8Vhh1cljUbIIjj56FQeL@5OpVJc/P9TjIOagzu@O26NpaUFQw@CQYs@@WUxTp93dPBwLTr/nI172LpKQSocaGjmWBUoft//hgWGlG6WjDnjcDGFpKwJ6@l71UvZJsIiQVmOM8Ud)

### Explanation:

`'PNDQ'=/]` creates an equality table

```
   'PNDQ' =/ 'PNNDNNQPDNPQND'
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

`1#.` finds the sum of each row of the table, thus the number of occurences of each value

```
   1#. 'PNDQ' =/ 'PNNDNNQPDNPQND'
3 6 3 2
```

`1#.*` finds the dot product of its left and right argument

```
    1 5 10 25(1#.*)3 6 3 2
113
```

`],` appends the dot product to the list of values

```
   1 5 10 25(],1#.*)1#.'PNDQ'=/] 'PNNDNNQPDNPQND'
3 6 3 2 113
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
«∨λð«fvO:»TM»₄τÞ•J
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCq+KIqM67w7DCq2Z2TzrCu1RNwrvigoTPhMOe4oCiSiIsIiIsInBubmRubnFwZG5wcW5kIl0=)

```
«∨λð«fvO:»TM»₄τÞ•J
«∨λð«               # Compressed string "pndq"
     f              # Convert to list of characters
      vO            # For each, how many times does it appear in the input?
        :           # Duplicate it
         »TM»       # Compressed integer 21241
             ₄τ     # To base-26 as list: [1, 5, 10, 25]
               Þ•   # Dot product of this and the other list
                 J  # Append this to the list
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>23</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
+Jm/Qd"PNDQ"s.b*NYJ[h05T25
```

Saved a byte thanks to @RK. Outputs as [P, N, D, Q, value].
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BJm%2FQd%22PNDQ%22s.b%2aNYJ%5Bh05T25&input=%22PNNDNNQPDNPQND%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
+Jm/Qd"PNDQ"s.b*NYJ[h05T25
 Jm/Qd"PNDQ"                Save the count of each coin (in PNDQ order) as J.
                   [h05T25  [1, 5, 10, 25].
             .b   J       For each pair of count and value...
               *NY          ... take the product...
            s               ... and get the sum.
+                          Stick that onto the list of counts.
```

Comment: You can condense the definition of J and the first usage of J to get `+Jm/Qd"PNDQ"s.b*NYJ[h05T25`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 59 bytes

```perl
for$i(P,N,D,Q){say s:$i:$\+={P,1,Q,25,D,10,N,5}->{$&}:eg}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glUyNAx0/HRSdQs7o4sVKh2Eol00olRtu2OkDHUCdQx8gUKGdoAFRiWqtrV62iVmuVml5bW/3/f0AgELr4@fn9yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2Bo8F@3wA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```ruby
->s{t=0;{P:1,N:5,D:10,Q:25}.map{|c,v|t+=v*m=s.count(c.to_s);m}<<t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664usTWwLo6wMpQx8/KVMfFytBAJ9DKyLRWLzexoLomWaespkTbtkwr17ZYLzm/NK9EI1mvJD@@WNM6t9bGpqT2f4FCWrRSgFIsF5jhB2O4wBiBcAYQwNl@LgEwDBMLgAO4iJ@fi59fYICLH0ihUux/AA)

Not great.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
"PNDQ"S¢D•Ωт•₂в*O)˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvlfKcDPJVAp@NAil0cNi86tvNgEpB41NV3YpOWveXrO/0qlw/sVdO0UDu9X0vkfwOXH5cIVyBUIBFyBfi4BMMwVAAdcAX5@Ln5@gQEufiApAA)

**Explanation**

```
"PNDQ"                # push this string
      S               # split to list of chars
       ¢              # count the occurrences of each in input
        D             # duplicate
         •Ωт•         # push 21241
             ₂в       # convert to a list of base 26 digits
               *      # element-wise multiplication
                O     # sum
                 )˜   # wrap in a flattened list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 148 bytes

```java
c->{int q=0,d=0,n=0,p=0;for(char w:c){if(w=='Q')q++;if(w=='D')d++;if(w=='N')n++;if(w=='P')p++;}return ""+q+","+d+","+n+","+p+","+(q*25+d*10+n*5+p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU@xboMwFNzzFU8s2DhBtFKWIipVZa0FyhhlcG1onRJjjEkUIb6dugQ1S7LlSe@k03t3utuzI1vVulB78TPyirUtfDCp@gWAVLYwJeMF0H5jjVRfYBD/Zma7A47jwb20llnJgUIHCYx89do7ETRJtBRulVudRHFZX3RweuG4lyU6JYmf@7ghJJ5Z6mNxZdTH6soyH2vHBlPYzijwPNIQb@kRMaGaUE@ImuB5TUTwFBEVrIl2IcfYxdTdZ@VizmmPtRRwcCXRpdV2x/BfX4DNubXFIaw7G2p3sZVCXWiQl@cpzbzQ1u@uxZsx7IwwxvE9zf3L7JbnDzPL/oem9GGut52GxTD@Ag)

Well it's only one byte shorter than the [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160745/78407) Java submission, but hey- shorter is shorter :D

**Explanation:**

```java
int q=0,d=0,n=0,p=0;    //Initialize too many integers
for(char w:c){    //Loop through each coin
  if(w=='Q')q++;if(w=='D')d++;if(w=='N')n++;if(w=='P')p++;    //Increment the correct coin
}return ""+q+","+d+","+n+","+p+","+(q*25+d*10+n*5+p);    //Return each coin count and the total monetary value
```

Comment: [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##rU/BaoNAFLznKx572nUTMYW0UrFQmmslkmPIYbur7aZmXdc1IYjfbrcaPCW3PHgDw3szzBzYiS1KnamD@O15weoaPplU7QxAKpuZnPEMknZrjVTfYDD/YWa3B06izr3UllnJIYEGYuj54q11IqjiYC7cKrc6DqK8HHVwfuWklTk@x3G4JBWl0UieQyIm8hISNZEwINqRzmS2MQohWlE0R1QMqAbUA@LKe1pR4S0DqrwV1S5fH7mEuvkqXMJr0FMpBRxdPzwW2u0Z@a8KsL3UNjv6ZWN97S62ULjxDUZpuk42yLflhyvwbgy7YEJIdE9z/3J1S9OHmW2mSdbJw1xvO3Wzrv8D "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 47 bytes

```
5R0TiE!vD;
5+@P@@t>b%m$.
a+$P$t
PrPrt
9s+r$P$rt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zTIICTTVbHMxZrLVNshwMGhxC5JNVdFjytRWyVApYQroCigqITLsli7CMgtKvn/PwAI/Pz8XFwCAQ)

The output format is `[P Q N D Value]`.

#### How it works

```
5R0TiE!vD;
       >b%m$.

5R0            Repeat command '0' (push 0) 5 times
   T           Set teleport location for later
    i          Input a char
     E         Pop if the last input was EOF; skip next otherwise

               If the last is EOF, the following is run:
      ! D;     Skip 'v', print the contents of the stack from bottom to top, then exit

               Otherwise the following is run:
       v
       >b%m$.  Take the top (input) modulo 11, and jump to (-1, input % 11)
               P%11 = 3, N%11 = 1, D%11 = 2, Q%11 = 4

5+@P@@t        Runs if the input is N
5+             Add 5 to top
  @            Rotate top 3 (the 3rd comes to the top)
   P           Increment the top
  @P@@         Increment the 3rd from top
      t        Teleport to the last 'T'

a+$P$t         Runs if the input is D
a+             Add 10 to top
  $            Swap top two
  $P$          Increment the 2nd from top
     t         Teleport to the last 'T'

PrPrt          Runs if the input is P
P              Increment the top
 r             Reverse the stack
 rPr           Increment the bottom
    t          Teleport to the last 'T'

9s+r$P$rt      Runs if the input is Q
9s+            Add 25 to the top ('s': add 16 to the top)
   r$P$r       Increment the 2nd from bottom
        t      Teleport to the last 'T'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 47 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
P1N5D10Q25=~s:\D:$\-=-$'*($n=s/$&//g);say$n:egr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z/A0M/UxdAg0MjUtq7YKsbFSiVG11ZXRV1LQyXPtlhfRU1fP13TujixUiXPKjW96P//QD@XABgO@JdfUJKZn1f8X7cg8b@ur6meoYGeIQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 112 bytes

```c
f(char *i){int c,d,v[5]={0};for(;c=*i++;v[d=(c|c/2)&3]++,v[4]+="AYJE"[d]-64);for(c=0;c<5;printf("%d,",v[c++]));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFBb4IwGIbv/RVfWFxawFlAvSAmS9hlhwaPi@FgWkESVxHQi/O3sxbFKcS9TUl5vrdvKR8f8u1KpvVLJvn2INYwKyuR7d42c9QiRYpMphrVCeabVQFmRk6ZrIDbwj4uJ3Fwomc/2RXY54GZWZZ/XIoA8x8@csmrF1uWco1jKzDevz4/jKWIh9MxaTbwgPp8NvFzdUSVYGMgbEOZuWXFhPjnOr0eWBI4odYEgxJgOAcwbCiJjxKsn2eE9Dd9rzKJtRul2IgM4ueHqsSGWmjAuiDsgkUPKPUYC6N2dmvRTb0KYyFjiyhkemO3mneB7ALRBfseUOoxKfJ29s68qVeRUki5z4XUGx@qSsW6OhQSaPPXRyaCCB6km9PIsWkzHNgVcF3@vThtRTEE7EnGxUftCYLwqeUaRgHB4h@TtrkqSDf1uWesgqgy3XX53uTZl@G4nrr5TZ2b0/bqKumx8/dJU5Xj2o7jIXNU/wI)

Output seq is now of P,Q,D,N,total-value
Works with both lower-case and upper-case inputs.

**Explanation:**

`"AYJE"` or `{64+1,64+25,64+10,64+5}` is. 64+value-of-coin.
`d=(c|c/2)&3` (used as index) has value `1,2,3,0` for `q,d,n,p` inputs respectively, in both upper and lower case.

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZFfb4IwFMXf@yluWFwo4OSP@oKYLGEve2jwcSE8mFaQxFUE9MX52dmtilOIO01J@d3TU8rlQ75Zyqx5ySXf7MUKZlUt8u3bek5ahKTMZYaoSXW@XpZGTo@5rIFbwjrEkyQ4nvx0W@o@D4zcNP1DPE7MQHv/@vzQYpEMp2N6iEWg8x8@cumrl6Dn4p9N/AKz61TXBsLSMI2bZkKpf2qy81FgVBSOpDXBoAIYzgE0Cyrqk1RXzxMh6nO@l7nUlZtkuhZp1C/2daVruFCAdUHYBYseQPUYC6N2dmvRTb0KYyFjiyhkamO3WnSB7ALRBbseQPWYFEU7e2fe1KtIKaTcFUKqjQ9VVLmq96UE@/zXRwaBCB6kmnOWY9nn4cC2hOvy78VpK8gIsCcZF59tTQiETy3XMBsILP4xKZuLQaqpzz1jDLLRdNfle5NnXYbjenjzmzo3t9urY9Jj5@@TppjjWo7jEWPU/AI "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: Eliminating c=0 was good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### [Kustom](https://help.kustom.rocks/s1-general/knowledgebase/top/c2-functions), 146 bytes (sort of)

It's hard to find challenges where this language works lol

```
$tc(count,gv(i),P)$
$tc(count,gv(i),N)$
$tc(count,gv(i),D)$
$tc(count,gv(i),Q)$
$gv(P)$,$gv(N)$,$gv(D)$,$gv(Q)$,$gv(P)+gv(N)*5+gv(D)*10+gv(Q)*25$
```

This is technically not one script, instead each line except the last is a global value, counting one byte extra for the name of each global ("i", "P", "N", "D", and "Q").

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/what-is-dotnet), 156 bytes

```
s=>{Func<char,int>f=i=>{return s.Split(i).Length-1;};var a=new[]{f('P'),f('N'),f('D'),f('Q')};return$"{string.Join(",",a)},{a[0]+a[1]*5+a[2]*10+a[3]*25}";};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 149 bytes

```java
a->{int[]c={0,0,0,0,0};for(String g:a){if(g=="P")c[0]+=1;if(g=="N")c[1]+=5;if(g=="D")c[2]+=10;if(g=="Q")c[3]+=25;}c[4]=c[0]+c[1]+c[2]+c[3];return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBboMwDIbvPIXVEwiKaDcuy5hUaddNm3ZEHEIIKB0NCEKnCeXZmZOmHWpycPT9ju3fR3qm267n8lh9L/1UtoIBa@k4whsVcvYAj5CKDzVlHA5wIY7mBVD/Sw1CNuYZECtqz4ZRUYXFDkAhg4VuX2b7g2VzErmrSd0NrgA0TzSYRe03Wbb52AQsT4ow2xFH3g3ZIUmv5NWQvclJrujToAdE@5Rolj8Wma1iP9pco5KBq2mQwIheyGVU59tNfO5EBSd0v7I2NGOw8n4TSvQm@c8NzDhDhKNFOLAmd7uqMJnG1C@Df8UsAFUQqCUEwzOkGMJw3c62/B0VP8XdpOIee6lW@lUuilUp7bavveUP)

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELzzFStOIBJE0uYSl6JIvbZq1SPywZiHnBKDjElVIX87XRy3RfVlrZmdnZ09syvbdn0lz@XH3I9FKzjwlg0DPDMhJw/wCakrVTNewQluiENzCix410rIZvmGxJLGs2XQTOOwEzBIYWbbx8kqeCqrTys@UFJ3yumhObJwEnXQpKn/6oc8T2gUEZ7vaJQu2IufHY4JAnsHPPnZLrHInUPe/Gy/9Bie39PUTrB6q1naiKr0qCRwYmZy29JFdsteO1HCBYOvUqlmCFexf4kCYy1RfoAJ/Te41QZXNeTfmUpsZjELivCPWcIjCwK5hGB5gAOWKFrbWcuvQVeXuBt13KOXbmVQ5oKuRhl3eOPN3w "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 50 bytes

```
P
P_
N
N5*
D
D10*
Q
Q25*
^
PNDQ_
O`.
(.)(\1*)
$.2¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D@AKyCey4/Lz1SLy4XLxdBAiyuQK9AIyIvjCvBzCYzn8k/Q49LQ09SIMdTS5FLRMzq07T9Qkx9QNVAhEHAF@rkEwDBXABwAtfu5@PkFBrj4gaQA) Outputs in the order D, N, P, Q, total. Explanation:

```
P
P_
N
N5*
D
D10*
Q
Q25*
```

Calculate the total by inserting `_`s corresponding to the value of each coin.

```
^
PNDQ_
```

Insert an extra copy of each character so there is at least one of each to match.

```
O`.
```

Sort the characters into order.

```
(.)(\1*)
$.2¶
```

Count the number of each character after the first.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 70 bytes

```
INPUT C$P=N+D+Q
WHILE""<C$INC VAR(POP(C$))WEND?P,N,D,Q,P+N*5+D*10+Q*25
```

Example:

```
? PNDNDNDQP
2   3   3   1   72
```

Explanation:

```
INPUT COINS$
P=N+D+Q 'create variables
WHILE COINS$>"" 'loop until the coin list is empty
 'pop a character from the coin list
 'and increment the variable with that name
 INC VAR(POP(COINS$))
WEND
PRINT P,N,D,Q,P+N*5+D*10+Q*25
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 149 bytes

```
f(char*s){int a[81]={},b[]={1,5,10,25},c=0;char*t,*v="PNDQ";for(t=s;*t;a[*t++]++);for(t=v;*t;printf("%d,",a[*t++]))c+=a[*t]*b[t-v];printf("%d\n",c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NasMwEITveYpFoaCfTYkKgYKinHwOzlnVwVnXiaB1iq3qYvzsqmVy6GlnZz92hnY3orwNPX39tp9wHGMbHq/3U@443ZtBjmIKfYTGvWtvpxmvbhkaD6j3@HaYkezerGBEmSyrz9WFme4x8GhHI6NpnIxKeaXE003F/RmWpx1nLy0yfCJCkLJFe3l1cZf8P@qjZ0jCzLl0@W5Cz9dSw40QSjpIuSxJwLQBgNDxcjppAatKTnthNnPOdX05V9Uf)

C doesn't have associative arrays, so I fake it (very inefficiently, memory-wise!) and then loop through again with a lookup array to add up the coins. It won't calculate foreign currency, though :-)

Comment: [133 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITvPsUSEfJXsSAixAhCvXiQepSaQ9naGtBWGu2l9NmjKR68zc58ywxGFaKf2hrv7@IKG/cqbDO/bX1J8Za33LHe1i/Is3VsdD9I1AtVNi1V3Kk8404IIwQbrZHvtNMkPSYnEohn@30uKZkVksgfzhgKHbThZLc/nEnmos7MVss/@lITiUwNPnQ/clvTcURboYRQA5x/j45BPwEAW9IQbWMGo@qy2DA1GbxP09MxST4 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 45 bytes

```
!s=(t=count.(["DNPQ"...],s);[t;[10 5 1 25]t])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDPasMwDMbZbfVTqO6hCbghTpcxKB475NKLZsN2Mj6EJYWO0UDiPM0uufShtqeZ_6RrJYzgJ32fjL7Pn-PXsZ5-7-5X0PVN2wNABYAAEkCRFczBc4DSFShKQpra1kITWlHxvHChOctD8twwQvGCHQi49FReaeTcU3VLPS_CsHIRO3PjwXkHc4WVvDw_obcsJi-2Yc1_BH3cdv2bRKwQlazQO8wGj05eMM69gTmP9rB5-tksB5FY8dGNJ5slmnoBzbLMsCHdabvT7iJluIexJp1F60PXQ7JH9vr-lgp_JrJ4qYeh7S0s9yiE46Q9NXF8mmL9Aw)